# what are different types of initialisations of arrays in java?

Tags: java

i got problem with this code.

```
public class Data {
    int[] d =new int[3];
    d[2]=4;
}
```

showing error

```
public class Data {
    int[] d ={1,2,3};
}
```

working fine. 
what is the difference between them.
can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement should go under a instance initialization block/Constructor of the class

```
d[2]=4;
```

Like,

```
public class Data {
int[] d =new int[3];
  {
   d[2]=4;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the former, the `d[2] = 4;` is not placed in the body of a method (or constructor) which is unacceptable. You can't just have random statements like that without it being in some sort of inner block.